# Change font color depending on a color assigned - Python

Tags: python

I have a table with records which have a Munsell color assigned which I could potentially turn in RGB. Is there a way for Python to read the RGB value and color a word accordingly? I've been researching on it, and it seems that it is maybe a css/js task, not a Python task but as I was doing the analysis in Python, I was wondering if I could create a word cloud with words colored in a corresponding color assigned.

Intput:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how you are viewing and doing the analysis "in Python"? Which library and/or commands are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have colors in CSV file. but if you want, you can output in the console like this:
I am not sure about RGB, but you can use Colorama for colors.
Something like:

```
from colorama import init, Fore
import pandas
init()
csv = pandas.read_csv(file_path)
for row, munsell, color in zip(csv['row'], csv['munsell'], csv['rgb']):
    print(getattr(Fore, color) + f"row: {row}, munsell: {munsell}" + Fore.RESET)
```

Fore.RESET is important. always add it at the end.
in your csv file, your RGB color codes need to match colorama's attributes.
example of a csv file:

```
row,munsell,rgb
1,10RP,RED
2,20RP, LIGHTRED_EX
```

EDIT:
You need to install [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)
And install pandas

EDIT2:
Changed the for loop a bit to match your case.